# Design considerations on JSON schema for scalars with a consistent attachment property

Tags: .net, json, schema, document-databases

I'm trying to create a JSON schema for the results of doing statistical analysis based on disparate pieces of data.

The current schema I have looks something like this:

```
{
    // Basic key information.
    video : "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uwfjpfK0jo",
    start : "00:00:00",
    end : null,

    // For results of analysis, to be populated:
    // *** This is where it gets interesting ***
    analysis : {
        game : {
            value: "Super Street Fighter 4: Arcade Edition Ver. 2012",
            confidence: 0.9725
        }
        teams : [
            {
                player : {
                    value : "Desk",
                    confidence: 0.95,
                }
                characters : [
                    {
                        value : "Hakan",
                        confidence: 0.80
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The issue is the tuples that are used to store a value and the confidence related to that value (i.e. `{ value : "some value", confidence : 0.85 }`), populated after the results of the analysis.

This leads to a creep of this tuple for every value.  Take a fully-fleshed out value from the `characters` array:

```
{
    name : {
        value : "Hakan",
        confidence: 0.80
    }
    ultra : {
        value: 1,
        confidence: 0.90
    }
}
```

As the structures that represent the values become more and more detailed (and more analysis is done on them to try and determine the confidence behind that analysis), the nesting of the tuples adds great deal of noise to the overall structure, considering that the final result (when verified) will be:

```
{
    name : "Hakan",
    ultra : 1
}
```

(And recall that this is just a nested value)

In .NET (in which I'll be using to work with this data), I'd have a little helper like this:

```
public class UnknownValue<T>
{     
    T Value { get; set; }
    double? Confidence { get; set; }
}
```

Which I'd then use like so:

```
public class Character 
{
    public UnknownValue<Character> Name { get; set; }
}
```

While the same as the JSON representation *in code*, it doesn't have the same creep because I don't have to redefine the tuple every time and property accessors hide the appearance of creep.  Of course, this is an apples-to-oranges comparison, the above is *code* while the JSON is *data*.

Is there a more formalized/cleaner/best practice way of containing the creep of these tuples in JSON, or is the approach above an accepted approach for the type of data I'm trying to store (and I'm just perceiving it the wrong way)?

Note, this is being represented in JSON because this will ultimately go in a document database (something like [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) or [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)).  I'm *not* concerned about being able to serialize into the object above, because I can always use [data transfer objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to facilitate getting data into/out of my underlying data store.

Comment: It would help if you are could be more specific about what seems unwieldy. JSON does not have the concept of a class.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I've updated the question to try and better reflect what seems unwieldy.  Basically, it's the creep of the tuple that contains the value and the confidence score.

Comment: So, are you saying that in .NET you are able to hide the complexity of your structure (tuples), but in JSON you are not?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals In .NET the code looks cleaner because of property accessor syntax.  But that's *code* this is data, and they are two different things.

Comment: Your JSON structure looks good to me. I see nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

This might be worse, or equal to your current situation: flatten the structure by splitting out confidence values into a second mirrored structure. It's flatter, but wider.

assessment->values->teams->second name = "Hakan"

assessment->confidence->teams->second name = 0.80

```
assessment: 
  {
     values: {
         game : "Super Street Fighter 4: Arcade Edition Ver. 2012".
         teams : [{ name: "desk", ultra: 2}, { name : "Hakan",  ultra : 1 }]
      },
      confidence: {
         game:  0.9725
         teams : [{ name : 0.95, ultra : 0.90 }, {name : 0.80, ultra : 0.20 }]
      }
   }
```

Comment: An interesting approach, so basically there's an implied mirror of the structure with the same property names and hierarchies, but all the values are the confidence scores?  I kind of like this, because I cold actually separate this out from the document if I wanted to, or, if it stays, it's neatly segregated in its own space, while still staying connected.